# Unable to generate same key pair from same random seed

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa, private-key, public-key

I am using java cryptography to generate public and private keys. I am using `String.getBytes()` to generate it. But While decrypting I am using the same `String.getBytes()` to get the keys. But I am not getting the same keys as same as previous. Please help. Below is the code sample.

```
KeyPairGenerator keyGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
SecureRandom ss = null;
ss = new SecureRandom("ABCD".getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT));
keyGenerator.initialize(512, ss);
KeyPair myKeyPair = keyGenerator.generateKeyPair();   

System.out.println(myKeyPair.getPrivate());
System.out.println(myKeyPair.getPublic());
```

Comment: The title could be improved.

Comment: Your code sample only produces one key pair - therefore it doesn't demonstrate your problem. Please adjust it so you have an example code that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code suggests you have a fundamental misunderstanding about how asymmetric cryptography is supposed to be used. Your sender and receiver should have their own, independent key pairs. The sender then encrypts data using the recipient's public key.

What you're doing is using a fixed string to generate the same key pair in two locations. That's not secure, as you've reduced your key space from 512 bits (which is already too small - use at *least* 1024-bits) down to the entropy associated with a (presumably short) string.

If you wish to have a "password" string used to derive keys at both ends, then use a symmetric algorithm (e.g. AES) and a password derivation function such as PBKDF2.

Comment: Is there any possible way to retrieve the same private and public key which was generated previously?. Even its insecure its ok for me the data is not so important.

Comment: @user2342659 Well, your current approach *would* produce the same key pair each time. If you're not getting that, you've made an error somewhere. Adjust your question to include an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem and we can help further.

Comment: Hi Jones, The same keys are generating in windows. But in Unix it fails. Also for your info the String "ABCD" is a DB value.

Comment: @user2342659 I would guess that the `SecureRandom` implementations differ on Windows and Unix? I'm not sure there is any promise that the same seed used on all platforms will produce the same values. I strongly encourage you to derive a symmetric key instead, using your string and a method such as [PBKDF2](https://gist.github.com/volker48/2853610).

Comment: @Jones I tried writing the above code as stanalone in unix. Its returning different values each time. But in windows its not the case

Comment: As stipulated before, you should not trust `SecureRandom` to generate the same random each time. The only way of getting the same random value each time is to use the "SHA1PRNG" of the Sun provider each time and immediately seed it with a known value. But even "SHA1PRNG" is not standardized. As Duncan already mentioned, this is not the correct way to generate keys (not even symmetric ones, let alone asymmetric ones).